# SQL Server query: eliminate the auxiliary table columns for intervals around midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I would like to eliminate the auxiliary table columns for intervals around midnight, ie.:

**With** auxiliary table columns:

```
timeIsValidFrom1    00:00:00
timeIsValidTo1      06:00:00
timeIsValidFrom2    18:00:00
timeIsValidTo2      00:00:00
```

**Without** auxiliary table columns:

```
timeIsValidFrom    18:00:00
timeIsValidTo      06:00:00
```

but if I do a query:

```
SELECT 
    cdr.*,
    tariff.*
FROM 
    AAA_Cdr AS cdr  
LEFT JOIN 
    AAA_Pricelists AS tariff ON ((cdr.timCallStarts >= timeIsValidFrom 
                             AND cdr.timCallStarts < tariff.timeIsValidTo));
```

I have get this result:

```
1   2017-04-01  11:30:00.0000000    11:35:15.0000000    1   Worktime    06:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
2   2017-04-01  18:45:02.0000000    18:46:05.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   2017-04-01  03:45:02.0000000    03:46:05.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   2017-04-01  14:30:00.0000000    14:35:15.0000000    1   Worktime    06:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
```

Problems are rows 2 and 3 which returns NULL and not "human time interval" as not return Freetime

Is there any function in SQL Server which can work with time intervals through midnight?

Thank you and best regards,

Petr

Example structure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AAA_Cdr]
(
    [intCdrId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dateInitialedDay] [date] NULL,
    [timCallStarts] [time](7) NULL,
    [timCallFinished] [time](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AAA_Cdr] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([intCdrId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AAA_Pricelists]
(
    [intPricelistId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [strName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [timeIsValidFrom] [time](7) NULL,
    [timeIsValidTo] [time](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AAA_Pricelists] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([intPricelistId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] ([intCdrId], [dateInitialedDay], [timCallStarts], [timCallFinished]) 
VALUES (1, CAST(N'2017-04-01' AS Date), CAST(N'11:30:00' AS Time), CAST(N'11:35:15' AS Time))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] ([intCdrId], [dateInitialedDay], [timCallStarts], [timCallFinished]) 
VALUES (2, CAST(N'2017-04-01' AS Date), CAST(N'18:45:02' AS Time), CAST(N'18:46:05' AS Time))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] ([intCdrId], [dateInitialedDay], [timCallStarts], [timCallFinished]) 
VALUES (3, CAST(N'2017-04-01' AS Date), CAST(N'03:45:02' AS Time), CAST(N'03:46:05' AS Time))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] ([intCdrId], [dateInitialedDay], [timCallStarts], [timCallFinished]) 
VALUES (4, CAST(N'2017-04-01' AS Date), CAST(N'14:30:00' AS Time), CAST(N'14:35:15' AS Time))
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Cdr] OFF
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Pricelists] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Pricelists] ([intPricelistId], [strName], [timeIsValidFrom], [timeIsValidTo]) 
VALUES (1, N'Worktime', CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'18:00:00' AS Time))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Pricelists] ([intPricelistId], [strName], [timeIsValidFrom], [timeIsValidTo]) 
VALUES (2, N'Freetime', CAST(N'18:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'06:00:00' AS Time))
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[AAA_Pricelists] OFF
GO
```

**UPDATE by comment: I want this result:**

```
1   2017-04-01  11:30:00.0000000    11:35:15.0000000    1   Worktime    06:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
2   2017-04-01  18:45:02.0000000    18:46:05.0000000    2   Freetime    18:00:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
3   2017-04-01  03:45:02.0000000    03:46:05.0000000    2   Freetime    18:00:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
4   2017-04-01  14:30:00.0000000    14:35:15.0000000    1   Worktime    06:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Such a great job posting ddl and sample data. I am struggling to understand what you are expecting for output from this sample data. Can you explain clearly what you want as output?

Comment: I update the end of question by section: "UPDATE by comment: I want this result"

Comment: Where do those values come from? I can't understand the rules here.

Comment: The table AAA_Pricelists is the codebook (defined by me=user). Here are stored records from-to is row true (time range, tarification operations). Table AAA_Cdr is CiscoDiagnosticReports, where are details about phone calls - when call start, when call end etc. For diagnostics I need select record (calls) when people do call (on work time, of free time etc.) and next drawing graphs with performance (pivot tables by resources, but that's another issue outside of SQL). I hope that I have already written clearly. When I find by Google, similar examples was call billing, which is very similar.

Comment: Let's try this approach. For the row with intCdrId = 2 where do the values come from? It looks like the values from AAA_Pricelists for intPricelistId = 2? So if your query with the left join does not find a match for pricelist you want to get this row. But how do you know which row from the pricelists table you want in that case?

Comment: >For the row with intCdrId = 2 where do the values come from?
Yes, it comes from AAA_Pricelists for intPricelistId = 2
>  So if your query with the left join does not find a match for pricelist you want to get this row.
If the query not find a match, the row is NULL, not append by different row

I apologize, but I do not know how to explain it anymore, I have tried to draw a graph with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this part of your query:

```
cdr.timCallStarts >= timeIsValidFrom AND cdr.timCallStarts < tariff.timeIsValidTo
```

For simplicity, I'll rewrite that as: `startOfRange <= testValue AND testValue < endOfRange`

Since all of these are time-only values, you need to think of time modeled on a 24-hour circular clock, rather than on a linear timeline.  Once you make that mental switch, you can easily handle time ranges that go over midnight.

Logically:

```
if startOfRange <= endOfRange
    startOfRange <= testValue AND testValue < endOfRange
else
    startOfRange <= testValue OR testValue < endOfRange
```

Basically, when the values are out of sequence, we assume they cross midnight, and thus we only care if the value is after the start (implicitly before midnight) OR if the value is before the end (implicitly after midnight).

Translating this back to your SQL:

```
SELECT cdr.*, tariff.*
FROM AAA_Cdr AS cdr
LEFT JOIN AAA_Pricelists AS tariff ON (
    timeIsValidFrom <= tariff.timeIsValidTo AND
    (cdr.timCallStarts >= timeIsValidFrom AND cdr.timCallStarts < tariff.timeIsValidTo)
) OR (
    timeIsValidFrom > tariff.timeIsValidTo AND
    (cdr.timCallStarts >= timeIsValidFrom OR cdr.timCallStarts < tariff.timeIsValidTo)
)
```